# ReadP's between returning an empty result

Tags: parsing, haskell

Consider the following snippet using [`ReadP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html):

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

readP_to_S (between (char '[') (char ']') (munch (/= ','))) "[234]"
```

It outputs

```
[]
```

According to the documentation,

> between :: ReadP open -> ReadP close -> ReadP a -> ReadP a Source#
>
> between open close p parses open, followed by p and finally close. Only the value of p is returned.

Consequently, I'd expect the return value to be

```
[("234", "")]
```

as the first parser matches the opening bracket, the second one the closing bracket, and the last matches everything except a comma. Why is it not doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.html#between)

```
between open close p = do _ <- open
                          x <- p
                          _ <- close
                          return x
```

it seems apparent that the `p` parser must not consume the characters needed by the `close` parser (which, to me, was not very intuitive).

This, for example

```
readP_to_S (between (char '[') (char ']') (munch (/= ']'))) "[234]"
```

gives

```
[("234","")]
```

Comment: The problem is not `between`, it's with `munch`.  From the documentation: "Always succeeds, exactly once having consumed all the characters Hence NOT the same as `many (satisfy p)`". That is, it locally disables backtracking, which prevents the correct parse from being found.  If `(many.satisfy)` is used in place of `munch` it should work correctly.

Comment: @luqui Thanks! If you could write that as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.